# Fix app keeps stopping made with android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I'm new in the android development field. Last night I made a simple calculator from a youtube tutorial and fortunately I've successfully made it. Here is the code

main.xml:-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top|center">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cal"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/fstval"
        android:id="@+id/etFirstValue"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/sndval"
        android:id="@+id/etSecondValue"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/ans"
        android:textColorHint="#FF0F00"
        android:id="@+id/tvAns"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/add"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="#4C5866"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:onClick="btnadd"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sub"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="#677789"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:id="@+id/btnSubtract"
        android:onClick="btnsub"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/mul"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="#405163"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:id="@+id/btnMultiply"
        android:onClick="btnmul"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/div"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="#19E6B1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/btnDivide"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:onClick="btndiv"/>

    

</LinearLayout>
```

mainactivity.java:-

```
    package com.mycompany.myapp;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.View.*;
import android.view.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    
    
    private EditText etn1;  
    private EditText etn2;
    private TextView tvResult;
    private Button btnadd , btnsub , btnmul , btndiv;
    
    
    
    
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        etn1 = findViewById(R.id.etFirstValue);
        etn2 = findViewById(R.id.etSecondValue);
        tvResult = findViewById(R.id.tvAns);
        
        
        Button btnadd = findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);  
        btnadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    
                    int n1 = Integer.parseInt(etn1.getText().toString());
                    int n2 = Integer.parseInt(etn2.getText().toString());

                    int add = n1 + n2;

                    tvResult.setText(String.valueOf(add));
                }
            
        
            
        });
        
        Button btnsub = findViewById(R.id.btnSubtract);  
        btnsub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    int n1 = Integer.parseInt(etn1.getText().toString());
                    int n2 = Integer.parseInt(etn2.getText().toString());

                    int add = n1 - n2;

                    tvResult.setText(String.valueOf(add));
                }



            });
        Button btnmul = findViewById(R.id.btnMultiply);  
        btnmul.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    int n1 = Integer.parseInt(etn1.getText().toString());
                    int n2 = Integer.parseInt(etn2.getText().toString());

                    int add = n1 * n2;

                    tvResult.setText(String.valueOf(add));
                }



            });
        Button btndiv = findViewById(R.id.btnDivide);  
        btndiv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    int n1 = Integer.parseInt(etn1.getText().toString());
                    int n2 = Integer.parseInt(etn2.getText().toString());

                    int add = n1 / n2;

                    tvResult.setText(String.valueOf(add));
                }



            });
        
        
        
    

            
        
        

    }

}
```

But the problem is when I don't put any value into the firstEditText or secondEditText or both of them and click on any button the app crashes and a pop up shows "myapp keeps stopping". I want something like " Please enter a value" shows on the blank EditText when I don't put any value to any of EditText. Help me please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app is crashing because when you don't enter any value and tap on buttons, it tries to parse an empty `string` to `int` which leads to a `NumberFormatException` and crashes your app.
However, you can first check if your edit texts are empty or not before parsing them, and show a toast or a snackbar if they are empty.

Use this

```
 String number1 = etn1.getText().toString();
 String number2 = etn2.getText().toString();
 if(number1.isBlank() || number2.isBlank()){
     Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a value", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {

 int n1 = Integer.parseInt(number1);
 int n2 = Integer.parseInt(number2);

 int add = n1 + n2;

 tvResult.setText(String.valueOf(add));
}
```

Comment: Yes ypu are right , i got it and fixed it thank you man ; )

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your input (say, `etn1.getText().toString()`) may not be a number. So you get NumberFormatException.
To fix this, rewrite your code like this:

```java
btnadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
int n1 = 0;
int n2 = 0;
try{
  n1 = Integer.parseInt(etn1.getText().toString());
}catch(Exception x) { 
  x.printStackTrace(); 
  n1 = 0;
}

try{
   n2 = Integer.parseInt(etn2.getText().toString());
}catch(Exception x) { 
  x.printStackTrace(); 
  n2 = 0;
}
 
                    int add = n1 + n2;

                    tvResult.setText(String.valueOf(add));
                }
            
        
            
        });
```

Comment: Yes your answer is right i finally got it , thank you :

Answer (score 0):

You're receiving a [NumberFormatException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) because when you run

```
Integer.parseInt(etn1.getText().toString())
```

When a EditText field has no value it returns `""`. "" cannot be transcribed into a number. Therefore, it throws the NumberFormat Exception.

There are a number of ways to handle this but i would suggest using [Uncle Bobs Clean Code methodology](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7EmboKQH8lM). You can encapsulate your within a try + catch block for each button click like so:

```
try{
  n1 = Integer.parseInt(etn1.getText().toString());
}catch(NumberFormatException x) { 
  x.printStackTrace(); 
  n1 = 0;
}
```

But i would suggest that given this code will have multiple uses across all button types, you move your `n` variables to global variables (at the top of the code base i.e `int n1`) and produce a new method such as

```
Private void setNumbers(){
try{
      n1 = Integer.parseInt(etn1.getText().toString());
      n2 = Integer.parseInt(etn2.getText().toString());
    }catch(NumberFormatException x) { 
      x.printStackTrace(); 
      n1 = 0;
      n2 = 0;
    }
}
```

Then within each Button onClick Listener could look like:

```
btndiv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                setNumbers();
                int divide = n1 / n2;
                tvResult.setText(String.valueOf(divide));
                } 
            });
```

Comment: Yes man you are right i got it, thank you : )